# Find all elements in a list that contain values in string array

Tags: c#, linq

If i have two elements in an array;

```
FirstName,LastName,Company
Donald,Duck,Disney
Daffey,Duck,Warner Brothers
```

Now my user enters "d", i should get both records.

Now my user enters "duck" and again i should get both records.

Now my user enters "duck disn" and i should only get the first record.

Is there a way to do this in linq?

*edit*

I have tried a few things, the latest is this;

```
var searchTerms = searchText.Split(" ".ToCharArray());

enquiryList = enquiryList.Where(x => 
    searchTerms.Contains(x.CompanyName.ToLower()) ||   
    searchTerms.Contains(x.FirstName.ToLower()) || 
    searchTerms.Contains(x.LastName.ToLower())).ToList();
```

But this only works if i enter the full words like disney and not part words like dis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var searchParts = searchText.Split(' ');
var matcheds = enquiryList.Where(enquiry =>
{
    var texts = new[] { enquiry.FirstName, enquiry.LastName, enquiry.Company };
    return searchParts.All(part => texts.Any(text =>
        text.IndexOf(part, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0));
});
```

Clear your mind. LINQ is easy.

You want items that `All` searched words are found in `Any` of `FirstName`, `LastName` or `Company`

Comment: If I enter "duck dis", this doesn't return the single record associated to duck,disney.

Comment: Hang on, weirdness happening

Comment: My apologies, I had two errors that were making things weird here.  They have been squashed and your code does indeed work really well thank you.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds to me that you want to search all three fields for matching string.

Assuming you  have a class called `Person` with three properties (`FirstName,LastName,Company`), you could do this.

```
var splits = searchText.Trim().Split(new string[] {" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

persons.Where(p=> splits.All(x=>  
                 p.FirstName.IndexOf(x, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >=0
              || p.LastName.IndexOf(x, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >=0
              || p.Company.IndexOf(x, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >=0));
```

Working [`Example`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Wc1zRv)

Comment: That's great but it need to search part of the string also not just the whole word

Comment: `IndexOf` looks for part of the string.

Comment: This doesn't cover the case : `Now my user enters "duck disn" and i should only get the first record.`

Comment: If i enter "duck disney" i still get all duck records where what i was wanting was the single record.

Comment: @griegs it is working check this [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Wc1zRv)

Comment: This would work as well but the accepted answer was first.  thank you anyway.  +1

Answer (score 1):

This covers all your cases:

```
string[] searchWords = new string[] { "duck", "disn" };
List<Duck> myList = new List<Duck>()
{
    new Duck() { FirstName = "Donald", LastName = "Duck", Company = "Disney" },
    new Duck() { FirstName = "Daffey", LastName = "Duck", Company = "Warner Brothers" }
};

var duckResults2 = (from duck in myList
                    where searchWords.All
                    (searchStr =>
                    duck.FirstName.IndexOf(searchStr, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0 ||
                    duck.LastName.IndexOf(searchStr, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0 ||
                    duck.Company.IndexOf(searchStr, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
                    select duck).ToList();
```